# Xamarin Forms: MasterPage Helper class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail, freshmvvm

My current app has multiple master detail pages. I want to create a helper class which has a function that accepts list of PageModels-Pages( ViewModels-views ) which I can iterate through and create master detail pages.

**MyCurrent Code:**

```
public static Page SetupMasterDetailNav<T,U>( Dictionary<T,string> Menu) 
        where T : class 
         //In Dictionary T is ViewModel(PageModel) , 
          String is name displayed on Master page  
    {
        var masterDetail = new FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<T,string> item in Menu)
        {
            masterDetail.AddPage<item.Key>(item.Value); 
        }
        masterDetail.Init("");
        return masterDetail;
    }
```

This code doesn't work.It tells me item.key is a variable and cannot be used as a type Can any one suggest me a better approach or how else I can achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AddPage<T>` method is a generic method, which expects a type. In this case it is `FreshBasePageModel`. The normal usage would be something like:

```
masterDetail.AddPage<MyViewModel>("MyPage", model);
```

or:

```
masterDetail.AddPage<MyViewModel>("MyPage");
```

Since your method is already generic, and seems you want it to be the type of the ViewModel you could simply do:

```
masterDetail.AddPage<T>(item.Value);
```

To do this you must change the your method signature to something like:

```
public static Page SetupMasterDetailNav<T,U>(Dictionary<T,string> Menu) 
    where T : FreshBasePageModel
```

Not sure what the `U` is used for in your case, you haven't shown usage of it.

Why are you even doing this is puzzling me.

Comment: Forgot to remove U. If I had to create a helper method where I pass view models to create master detail page. What would be the better approach?
As you said `masterDetail.AddPage<MyViewModel>("MyPage");` is the normal usage but instead of using 'MyViewModel' and 'MyPage' I want to pass list of all view models I want to create..

Comment: How do you construct this list?

Comment: In our app, we have multiple master detail pages so I want to create one helper function that i could access whenever I want to create master detail page. I want to call a helper class and pass list of view models ( may be use dictionary? ) and its name which can be iterated by the helper function to create master detail page.

Comment: If I want to have master-detail page for with 3 items settingviewmodel,signoutViewModel, reportViewModel then I want to pass those three view models into the helper class along with the string that needs to be displayed on the page which the helper function can look up and help create the master detail page.
Does it make sense ?